# Why does this query make my whole database freeze?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT * FROM `groupon-spain-6sep-2011`, `Hoja1`,`GroupaliaJuly2011` 
WHERE `groupon-spain-6sep-2011`.`code`= 5654 
    OR  `Hoja1`.`code` = "5654 
    OR `GroupaliaJuly2011`.`code` = 5654
```

Comment: This is why implicit join syntax is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing any join condition relating the tables to each other so are doing a cartesian join of 3 tables.

I recommend always using explicit join syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM   `groupon-spain-6sep-2011`
       JOIN `hoja1` ON `groupon-spain-6sep-2011`.foo=`hoja1`.foo
       JOIN `groupaliajuly2011` ON `groupaliajuly2011`.`foo` = `hoja1`.foo
WHERE  `groupon-spain-6sep-2011`.`code` = 5654
        OR `hoja1`.`code` = 5654
        OR `groupaliajuly2011`.`code` = 5654
```

Although it is possible that you might be wanting a Union here I think anyway?

Comment: The join style SQL you wrote has different meaning from the OP's. You can NOT infer that the columns involved are foreign keys from the OP's SQL. Tuples satisfying the OP's SQL just have to have one column equals to '5654', and the other two columns can be anything, let alone being equal.

Comment: @Spirit- Of course it has different meaning. The OP's is doing an unintentional cross join! My answer demonstrates join syntax using arbitrary column names as we have no information about table structure or relationships.  I suspect based on the table names they probably need `UNION` not `JOIN` anyway here as my last line suggests.

Comment: Agree. Maybe the Cartesian product form of SQL seems to be an union operation to someone new to SQL like the OP.

Comment: I doubt someone new to SQL is going to know what "Cartesian product" means either.

Answer (score 6):

The query you posed involves the Cartesian product(also known as CROSS JOIN in standard SQL, thanks for the advice @onedaywhen) of three tables, the amount of record involves will be size(A) * size(B) * size(C). So if the total product is large enough, it will fill a significant amount of memory, which will make your database unable to response to any other request, and that will lead to the 'freeze' of your database.

I noticed that you want either of the three specified columns to be the same value '5654', so you can selet tuples from three table respectively, and then UNION them, instead of doing Cartesian product of them like you're doing it now, since I don't think the Cartesian product you're making makes any sense. That will save a GREAT number of memory.

Comment: First paragraph is clear and answers the why. The second one, not so much. How one should combine tuples? In a way, he is already doing that, combining tuples. If you mean to use `UNION`, write it.

Comment: @ypercube. Suggestion accepted =) I didn't use the word 'UNION' because I'm not  quite sure it's the way he/she wants it. Anyway, your suggestion makes it clearer.

Comment: +1 but I doubt someone new to SQL is going to know what "Cartesian product" means unless they are from a mathematics background and even then the relational Cartesian product is different. Can you used another term please. Standard SQL calls it `CROSS JOIN`, for example.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Unfortunately in MySQL [`CROSS JOIN` is the syntactic equivalent of `INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) which somewhat confuses the issue here.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I did not know that! The wacky world of MySQL, eh? Looks like you get all the dangers of the pre-SQL-92 Standard join syntax into the bargain :)

Answer (score 6):

You might want to do a union instead:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM groupon-spain-6sep-2011
    WHERE code = 5654
UNION SELECT * 
    FROM Hoja1
    WHERE code = 5654
UNION SELECT * 
    FROM GroupaliaJuly2011
    WHERE code = 5654
```

Comment: +1 But I think he may also want to know the reason for the 'freeze' of the databas, which is stated in my answer.

Comment: @Spirit Zang: Yes. Both you Martin answered that, so I didn't need to =) Hence +1 for you.

Comment: Of course you should never use select * (and it won't work in a UNION if the tables have differnt structures). OP should also consider if UNION ALL will work as it is faster. It will only work though if none of teh records could be in more than one table.